# SendMail Bounce Back Missing Send To Address in Transcript

Tags: debian, sendmail, dkim, email-bounces, opendkim

SendMail bounce back response is showing a blank To address. How can I correct this so the bounce back includes the To address?

This began occurring after installing opendkim on the server and before DKIM was enabled. Sendmail version did not change.

apt-cache show opendkim | grep Version

```
Version: 2.11.0~alpha-12
```

apt-cache show sendmail | grep sendmail

```
Version: 8.15.2-14~deb10u1
```

Transcript

```
The original message was received at Fri, 2 Sep 2022 10:37:32 -0400
from localhost [127.0.0.1]

----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----

(reason: 550 No Such User Here)

----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to mail.mindsprings.com.:
>>> DATA
<<< 550 No Such User Here
550 5.1.1 ... User unknown
<<< 503-All RCPT commands were rejected with this error:
<<< 503-No Such User Here
<<< 503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA
Return-Path:
Received: from xxx.example.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])
by xxx.example.com (8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-14~deb10u1) with ESMTP id 282EbWaw025433
for ; Fri, 2 Sep 2022 10:37:32 -0400
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=example.com;
s=default; t=1662129452;
bh=qECblk8t3o2e36JMaANxcnSTuDE+sQrIDbjMJtBq9ds=;
h=Date:From:To:CC:Subject;
b=ACoi7O+Zq09bDtug0aomOUUWSb+A6zVfDZsMKKWHtN/xewo3TiJkA/TTXvr2Q5VI6
qIrBAywVhqJQUR1jPYij3LXG3SVmUdUBKpbc2YDzJN5GutLYU29oWJwcKkNJ9iMEP5
kmRXCBcXSjCWwC4vNm46T9OZKvSVopfcL2E2Uw+Q=
Received: (from www-data@localhost)
by xxx.example.com (8.15.2/8.15.2/Submit) id 282EbWa7025428;
Fri, 2 Sep 2022 10:37:32 -0400
Date: Fri, 2 Sep 2022 10:37:32 -0400
Message-Id:
X-Authentication-Warning: xxx.example.com: www-data set sender to "Jane Smith" using -f
From: "Jane Smith"
To:
CC:
Subject: test
x-mailer: XXX
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="---------------------XXXXX166212945249951r"
```

Comment: `503-No Such User Here` did you see that?

Comment: @djdomi Yes, this is unrelated. If the email is sent to validaddress@gmail.com and invalidaddress@gmail.com, I do not get code 503. I only get code 503 if I send the email only to invalidaddress@gmail.com. Both situations I get a bounce back missing the To address.